# fscanf a file with doubles and characters

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

I have a file which will contains basic mathematical operations. An example:

```
1 + 23 / 42 * 23
```

I am scanning the file, putting each "element" into a struct and pushing it onto a stack I created. The problem I have is as follows:

```
char reading;
while(!feof(fp)) {
  fscanf(fp, "%c", &reading);
  ....
```

This will scan `1`, `+`, `2`, `3` instead of `1`, `+`, `23`. What are other suggestions to use one `fscanf` and have it iterate and read all the inputs as intended to with respect to their type?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `fscanf()` a bit different, like this:

```
char buf[16];
int val;
char op;

while (!feof(fp)) {
    fscanf("%s ", buf); // Note: Without ' ' the last value would be readed twice
    if (buf[0] == '+' || buf[0] == '-' || buf[0] == '/' || buf[0] == '*') {
        op = buf[0];
        // do something with op
    } else {
        sscanf(buf, "%d", &val);
        // do something with val
    }
}
```

The size of `buf` must be something which could store the length of your numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`fscanf` is the wrong tool for this job, because it needs a format string that knows in advance what format to expect.  Your best bet is to read a character at a time and build up tokens that you can then interpret, especially if you'll have to accept input like `2+2` (no spaces), or `(1 + 23) / 42`, with parentheses.

Comment: So you suggest using `strtok` as opposed to `fscanf`?

Comment: If you can be certain that all of your tokens will have whitespace between them, then `strtok` would work.  But most expression evaluators don't require the user to make things so spaced out.